# Excel VBA - Selecting Row in For Loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a for loop that goes through Column I and looks for when the value exceeds a certain point. It then inserts a row.
I need to edit this row. I need to merge a portion of it and insert text and what not. Right now, my code just merges the entire columns of E - I. How do I get it to just merge that row?

This is what I have right now:

```
For Each cel In Range("I:I")
    If cel.Value >= "15AQ08" And Pick = "Truck" And cel.Row <> 1 Then
        cel.EntireRow.Insert
        Range("E:I").Merge
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Range("E:I").Merge
```

To merge to newly inserted row, use

```
cel.Offset(-1, -4).Resize(, 5).Merge
```

or, to merge the row containing the match, use

```
cel.Offset(0, -4).Resize(, 5).Merge
```

---

To get a reference to the range, use

```
Set rng = cel
rng.Offset(-1, -4).Resize(, 5).Merge
```

then use `rng` to write a value to, and `rng.mergearea` to format